# Remove duplicate nodes in tree

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have a `/tree-list` endpoint that returns a list of the `Group` class where one of its attributes returns data from the `Person` class in tree format, this works with one record in the list, but when the list has more of a record, the `Person` tree nodes are duplicated, what should I do to prevent this from happening?

**List with a record:**

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Group 1",
        "personList": [
            {
                "id": 1,
                "fullName": "William",
                "children": [
                    {
                        "id": 2,
                        "fullName": "Henry",
                        "children": [
                            {
                                "id": 3,
                                "fullName": "Matt",
                                "children": [
                                    {
                                        "id": 7,
                                        "fullName": "Sophi",
                                        "children": [],
                                        "rootParentId": 1
                                    }
                                ],
                                "rootParentId": 1
                            },
                            {
                                "id": 4,
                                "fullName": "Alisa",
                                "children": [
                                    {
                                        "id": 6,
                                        "fullName": "Alexa",
                                        "children": [],
                                        "rootParentId": 1
                                    }
                                ],
                                "rootParentId": 1
                            }
                        ],
                        "rootParentId": 1
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 5,
                        "fullName": "May",
                        "children": [],
                        "rootParentId": 1
                    }
                ],
                "rootParentId": 1
            },
            {
                "id": 8,
                "fullName": "Olivia",
                "children": [
                    {
                        "id": 9,
                        "fullName": "John",
                        "children": [
                            {
                                "id": 11,
                                "fullName": "Oliver",
                                "children": [],
                                "rootParentId": 8
                            },
                            {
                                "id": 12,
                                "fullName": "Mia",
                                "children": [],
                                "rootParentId": 8
                            }
                        ],
                        "rootParentId": 8
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 10,
                        "fullName": "Mary",
                        "children": [
                            {
                                "id": 13,
                                "fullName": "Evelyn",
                                "children": [],
                                "rootParentId": 8
                            }
                        ],
                        "rootParentId": 8
                    }
                ],
                "rootParentId": 8
            },
            {
                "id": 14,
                "fullName": "Eric",
                "children": [],
                "rootParentId": null
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

**List with more records:**

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Group 1",
        "personList": [
            {
                "id": 1,
                "fullName": "William",
                "children": [
                    {
                        "id": 2,
                        "fullName": "Henry",
                        "children": [
                            {
                                "id": 3,
                                "fullName": "Matt",
                                "children": [
                                    {
                                        "id": 7,
                                        "fullName": "Sophi",
                                        "children": [],
                                        "rootParentId": 1
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "id": 7,
                                        "fullName": "Sophi",
                                        "children": [],
                                        "rootParentId": 1
                                    }
                                ],
                                "rootParentId": 1
                            },
                            {
                                "id": 4,
                                "fullName": "Alisa",
                                "children": [
                                    {
                                        "id": 6,
                                        "fullName": "Alexa",
                                        "children": [],
                                        "rootParentId": 1
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "id": 6,
                                        "fullName": "Alexa",
                                        "children": [],
                                        "rootParentId": 1
                                    }
                                ],
                                "rootParentId": 1
                            }
    
....

    ]
```

**Full response:**

```
[{"id":1,"name":"Group 1","personList":[{"id":1,"fullName":"William","children":[{"id":2,"fullName":"Henry","children":[{"id":3,"fullName":"Matt","children":[{"id":7,"fullName":"Sophi","children":[],"rootParentId":1},{"id":7,"fullName":"Sophi","children":[],"rootParentId":1}],"rootParentId":1},{"id":4,"fullName":"Alisa","children":[{"id":6,"fullName":"Alexa","children":[],"rootParentId":1},{"id":6,"fullName":"Alexa","children":[],"rootParentId":1}],"rootParentId":1},{"id":3,"fullName":"Matt","children":[{"id":7,"fullName":"Sophi","children":[],"rootParentId":1},{"id":7,"fullName":"Sophi","children":[],"rootParentId":1}],"rootParentId":1},{"id":4,"fullName":"Alisa","children":[{"id":6,"fullName":"Alexa","children":[],"rootParentId":1},{"id":6,"fullName":"Alexa","children":[],"rootParentId":1}],"rootParentId":1}],"rootParentId":1},{"id":5,"fullName":"May","children":[],"rootParentId":1},{"id":2,"fullName":"Henry","children":[{"id":3,"fullName":"Matt","children":[{"id":7,"fullName":"Sophi","children":[],"rootParentId":1},{"id":7,"fullName":"Sophi","children":[],"rootParentId":1}],"rootParentId":1},{"id":4,"fullName":"Alisa","children":[{"id":6,"fullName":"Alexa","children":[],"rootParentId":1},{"id":6,"fullName":"Alexa","children":[],"rootParentId":1}],"rootParentId":1},{"id":3,"fullName":"Matt","children":[{"id":7,"fullName":"Sophi","children":[],"rootParentId":1},{"id":7,"fullName":"Sophi","children":[],"rootParentId":1}],"rootParentId":1},{"id":4,"fullName":"Alisa","children":[{"id":6,"fullName":"Alexa","children":[],"rootParentId":1},{"id":6,"fullName":"Alexa","children":[],"rootParentId":1}],"rootParentId":1}],"rootParentId":1},{"id":5,"fullName":"May","children":[],"rootParentId":1}],"rootParentId":1},{"id":8,"fullName":"Olivia","children":[{"id":9,"fullName":"John","children":[{"id":11,"fullName":"Oliver","children":[],"rootParentId":8},{"id":12,"fullName":"Mia","children":[],"rootParentId":8},{"id":11,"fullName":"Oliver","children":[],"rootParentId":8},{"id":12,"fullName":"Mia","children":[],"rootParentId":8}],"rootParentId":8},{"id":10,"fullName":"Mary","children":[{"id":13,"fullName":"Evelyn","children":[],"rootParentId":8},{"id":13,"fullName":"Evelyn","children":[],"rootParentId":8}],"rootParentId":8},{"id":9,"fullName":"John","children":[{"id":11,"fullName":"Oliver","children":[],"rootParentId":8},{"id":12,"fullName":"Mia","children":[],"rootParentId":8},{"id":11,"fullName":"Oliver","children":[],"rootParentId":8},{"id":12,"fullName":"Mia","children":[],"rootParentId":8}],"rootParentId":8},{"id":10,"fullName":"Mary","children":[{"id":13,"fullName":"Evelyn","children":[],"rootParentId":8},{"id":13,"fullName":"Evelyn","children":[],"rootParentId":8}],"rootParentId":8}],"rootParentId":8},{"id":14,"fullName":"Eric","children":[],"rootParentId":null}]},{"id":2,"name":"Group 2","personList":[{"id":1,"fullName":"William","children":[{"id":2,"fullName":"Henry","children":[{"id":3,"fullName":"Matt","children":[{"id":7,"fullName":"Sophi","children":[],"rootParentId":1},{"id":7,"fullName":"Sophi","children":[],"rootParentId":1}],"rootParentId":1},{"id":4,"fullName":"Alisa","children":[{"id":6,"fullName":"Alexa","children":[],"rootParentId":1},{"id":6,"fullName":"Alexa","children":[],"rootParentId":1}],"rootParentId":1},{"id":3,"fullName":"Matt","children":[{"id":7,"fullName":"Sophi","children":[],"rootParentId":1},{"id":7,"fullName":"Sophi","children":[],"rootParentId":1}],"rootParentId":1},{"id":4,"fullName":"Alisa","children":[{"id":6,"fullName":"Alexa","children":[],"rootParentId":1},{"id":6,"fullName":"Alexa","children":[],"rootParentId":1}],"rootParentId":1}],"rootParentId":1},{"id":5,"fullName":"May","children":[],"rootParentId":1},{"id":2,"fullName":"Henry","children":[{"id":3,"fullName":"Matt","children":[{"id":7,"fullName":"Sophi","children":[],"rootParentId":1},{"id":7,"fullName":"Sophi","children":[],"rootParentId":1}],"rootParentId":1},{"id":4,"fullName":"Alisa","children":[{"id":6,"fullName":"Alexa","children":[],"rootParentId":1},{"id":6,"fullName":"Alexa","children":[],"rootParentId":1}],"rootParentId":1},{"id":3,"fullName":"Matt","children":[{"id":7,"fullName":"Sophi","children":[],"rootParentId":1},{"id":7,"fullName":"Sophi","children":[],"rootParentId":1}],"rootParentId":1},{"id":4,"fullName":"Alisa","children":[{"id":6,"fullName":"Alexa","children":[],"rootParentId":1},{"id":6,"fullName":"Alexa","children":[],"rootParentId":1}],"rootParentId":1}],"rootParentId":1},{"id":5,"fullName":"May","children":[],"rootParentId":1}],"rootParentId":1},{"id":8,"fullName":"Olivia","children":[{"id":9,"fullName":"John","children":[{"id":11,"fullName":"Oliver","children":[],"rootParentId":8},{"id":12,"fullName":"Mia","children":[],"rootParentId":8},{"id":11,"fullName":"Oliver","children":[],"rootParentId":8},{"id":12,"fullName":"Mia","children":[],"rootParentId":8}],"rootParentId":8},{"id":10,"fullName":"Mary","children":[{"id":13,"fullName":"Evelyn","children":[],"rootParentId":8},{"id":13,"fullName":"Evelyn","children":[],"rootParentId":8}],"rootParentId":8},{"id":9,"fullName":"John","children":[{"id":11,"fullName":"Oliver","children":[],"rootParentId":8},{"id":12,"fullName":"Mia","children":[],"rootParentId":8},{"id":11,"fullName":"Oliver","children":[],"rootParentId":8},{"id":12,"fullName":"Mia","children":[],"rootParentId":8}],"rootParentId":8},{"id":10,"fullName":"Mary","children":[{"id":13,"fullName":"Evelyn","children":[],"rootParentId":8},{"id":13,"fullName":"Evelyn","children":[],"rootParentId":8}],"rootParentId":8}],"rootParentId":8},{"id":14,"fullName":"Eric","children":[],"rootParentId":null}]}]
```

**My Classes**

**Models**

```
@Entity
@JsonIgnoreProperties({"hibernate_lazy_initializer", "handler"})
@EqualsAndHashCode(onlyExplicitlyIncluded = true)
public class Person {

    @Id
    @Getter
    @Setter
    @EqualsAndHashCode.Include
    private Long id;

    @Getter
    @Setter
    private String fullName;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @Getter
    @Setter
    @JsonIgnore
    private Person parent;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @Getter
    @Setter
    @JsonIgnore
    private Person rootParent;

    @Transient
    @Getter
    @Setter
    public List<Person> children = new ArrayList<>();

    public Long getRootParentId() {
        if (parent != null) {
            return parent.getRootParentId();
        } else if (children != null && !children.isEmpty()) {
            return id;
        } else return null;
    }

}


@Entity
    @JsonIgnoreProperties({"hibernate_lazy_initializer", "handler"})
    @EqualsAndHashCode(onlyExplicitlyIncluded = true)
    public class Group {
    
        @Id
        @Getter
        @Setter
        @EqualsAndHashCode.Include
        private Long id;
    
        @Getter
        @Setter
        private String name;
    
    }
```

**DTO**

```
@Data
@Builder
@JsonIgnoreProperties({"hibernate_lazy_initializer", "handler"})
public class GroupDTO {

    private Long id;
    private String name;
    private List<Person> personList;

    public GroupDTO(Group group) {
        this.id = group.getId();
        this.name = group.getName();
    }

    public GroupDTO(Long id, String name, List<Person> personList) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.personList = personList;
    }
}
```

**Repository**

```
@Repository
public interface PersonRepo extends JpaRepository<Person, Long> {

    @Query("SELECT p FROM Person p "
            + " WHERE p.parent.id IS NULL")
    List<Person> findRoots();

    @Query("SELECT p FROM Person p"
            + " WHERE p.rootParent.id IN :rootIds ")
    List<Person> findChildrenInRoots(@Param("rootIds") List<Long> rootIds);

}
```

**Controller**

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/v1/person")
public class PersonController {

    private final PersonRepo personRepo;

    public PersonController(PersonRepo personRepo) {
        this.personRepo = personRepo;
    }
    
    @GetMapping("/tree-list")
    @Transactional(readOnly = true)
    public List<GroupDTO> getChildrenList() {
        List<Group> groupEntityList = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 1; i <= 2; i++) {
            Group group = new Group();
            group.setId((long) i);
            group.setName("Group " + i);
            groupEntityList.add(group);
        }
        List<GroupDTO> groupList = groupEntityList.stream().map(GroupDTO::new).collect(Collectors.toList());

        groupList.forEach(group -> {
                    List<Person> rootNodes = new ArrayList<>(personRepo.findRoots());

                    List<Long> rootNodesIds = rootNodes.stream().map(Person::getId).collect(Collectors.toList());

                    List<Person> children = new ArrayList<>(personRepo.findChildrenInRoots(rootNodesIds));

                    children.forEach(subCategory -> subCategory.getParent().getChildren().add(subCategory));
                    group.setPersonList(rootNodes);
                }
        );
        return groupList;
    }
}
```

**Tree data**

```
insert into PERSON values (1,'William',null, null);
insert into PERSON values (2,'Henry',1,1);
insert into PERSON values (3,'Matt',2,1);
insert into PERSON values (4,'Alisa',2,1);
insert into PERSON values (5,'May',1,1);
insert into PERSON values (6,'Alexa',4,1);
insert into PERSON values (7,'Sophi',3,1);
insert into PERSON values (8,'Olivia',null,null);
insert into PERSON values (9,'John',8,8);
insert into PERSON values (10,'Mary',8,8);
insert into PERSON values (11,'Oliver',9,8);
insert into PERSON values (12,'Mia',9,8);
insert into PERSON values (13,'Evelyn',10,8);
insert into PERSON values (14,'Eric',null,null);
```